# How to compare dates only (and not the time) in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have 2 datetime objects. One only has the date and the other one has date & time. I want to compare the dates only (and not the time). 
This is what I have:

```
d2=datetime.date(d1.year,d1.month,d1.day)
print d2 == d1.date
```

It prints out false. Any idea why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
d1.date() == d2.date()
```

From the Python [doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date):

> `datetime.date()` Return date object with same year, month and day.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing `d1 == d2.date()` and it worked. because d1 is a date time, so I can't do d1.date() as you suggested. Thanks though!

Comment: thanks, would be great to point out how to compare if a date is before or after another date, something like `d1.date() < d2.date()`. Can you include in your answer how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Cast your datetime object into a date object first. Once they are of the same type, the comparison will make sense.

```
if d2.date() == d1.date():
    print "same date" 
else:
    print "different date"
```

For your case above:-

```
In [29]: d2
Out[29]: datetime.date(2012, 1, 19)

In [30]: d1
Out[30]: datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 19, 0, 0)
```

So,

```
In [31]: print d2 == d1.date()
True
```

All you needed for your case was to make sure you are executing the date method with the brackets `()`.

Answer (score 2):

For those who wants to compare specific date with today date.

```
import datetime

# Set specific date
date = '2020-11-21'

# Cast specific date to Date Python Object
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

# Get today date with Date Python Object
today = datetime.date.today()

# Compare the date
isYesterday = date < today
isToday     = date == today
isTomorrow  = date > today
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> datetime.date.today() == datetime.datetime.today().date()
True
```

[For more info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR:**

The DateTime Object has a built in function called date(). You can use this to get the date only of the datetime object.

**Example:**

```
current_time_dt_object  = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time_only_date = current_time_dt_object.date()
```

You can now use this current_time_only_date as do any equality operation you want.