# remove non matching rows from two dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes
1st

```
                     dt   SRNE   CRSR     GME  ...    ASO    TH     DTE    ATH
0   2021-04-12 00:00:00  6.940  33.67  141.09  ...  32.29  3.42  135.63  50.80
1   2021-04-13 00:00:00  6.930  33.71  140.99  ...  31.68  3.39  137.63  50.88
2   2021-04-14 00:00:00  7.385  33.93  166.53  ...  30.82  3.23  138.72  53.35
3   2021-04-15 00:00:00  7.440  34.16  156.44  ...  30.54  3.26  139.48  54.14
4   2021-04-16 00:00:00  7.490  32.60  154.69  ...  30.77  2.79  140.68  55.45
```

2nd

```
                               dt  text compare
0       2021-03-19 14:59:49+00:00  i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...       1
1       2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  oh this isn’t good       0
2       2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  lads why is my account covered in more red ink...       0
3       2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  i'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...       0
4       2021-03-19 14:59:52+00:00  the sell offs will continue until moral improves.       0
```

I want to remove rows that don't match with both dataframes by looking at the data  column.
I tried

```
discussion = discussion[discussion['dt'] == price['dt']]
```

It gives an error ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
I assume it is because the column names don't match
Appreciate your help

Comment: use `isin` i.e. `discussion[discussion['dt'].isin(price['dt'].to_list())]`

Comment: it returns an empty dataframe

Comment: That is because none of the values match

Comment: you mean minutes and seconds?

Comment: Yeas, equality works with exact match only, the entire datetime value should match

Comment: what if I want to check year month and day and forget about minutes

Comment: Then you either  need to get rid of minute hour and second part from the dataframe indices, or create new column having year month day only, then do the comparison on the basis of the new value.

Comment: If the `dt` column is of datetime, then you can use `date()` accessor, you can take a look at [How to compare dates only (and not the time) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227597/how-to-compare-dates-only-and-not-the-time-in-python)

Comment: yeah thank you I got it

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
discussion = pd.DataFrame([['2021-04-12 00:00:00',6.940,33.67,141.09,32.29,  3.42,  135.63,  50.80],
                   ['2021-04-13 00:00:00',6.930,33.71,140.99,31.68,  3.39,  137.63,  50.88],
                   ['2021-04-14 00:00:00',7.385,33.93,166.53,30.82,  3.23,  138.72,  53.35],
                   ['2021-04-15 00:00:00',7.440,34.16,156.44,30.54,  3.26,  139.48,  54.14],
                   ['2021-04-16 00:00:00',7.490,32.60,154.69,30.77,  2.79,  140.68,  55.45]],
                  columns=['dt',   'SRNE',   'CRSR',     'GME', 'ASO',    'TH',     'DTE',    'ATH'])
discussion['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(discussion['dt'])
price = pd.DataFrame([['2021-04-12 23:30:00','i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...',       1],
                    ['2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00','oh this isn’t good       ',0],
                    ['2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00','lads why is my account covered in more red ink... ',      0],
                    ['2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00','im tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup... ',      0],
                    ['2021-04-16 12:45:00','the sell offs will continue until moral improves. ',      0]],
                   columns=['dt',  'text', 'compare'])
price['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(price['dt'], utc=True)
discussion = discussion[discussion['dt'].dt.date.isin(price['dt'].dt.date)]
discussion
```

Output

```
       dt                       SRNE    CRSR    GME     ASO     TH      DTE ATH
0   2021-04-12  6.94    33.67   141.09  32.29   3.42    135.63  50.80
4   2021-04-16  7.49    32.60   154.69  30.77   2.79    140.68  55.45
```